# 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got spacy.tokens.doc.Doc)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a dataframe:

```
train_review = train['review']
train_review
```

It looks like:

```
0      With all this stuff going down at the moment w...
1      \The Classic War of the Worlds\" by Timothy Hi...
2      The film starts with a manager (Nicholas Bell)...
3      It must be assumed that those who praised this...
4      Superbly trashy and wondrously unpretentious 8...
```

I add the tokens into a string:

```
train_review = train['review']
train_token = ''
for i in train['review']:
   train_token +=i
```

What I want is to tokenize the reviews using Spacy.
Here is what I tried, but I get the following error:

> Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got
>   spacy.tokens.doc.Doc)

How can I solve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are taking spacy.tokens from your dataframe and appending them to a string, so you should cast it to `str`.
Like this:

```
train_review = train['review']
train_token = ''
for i in train['review']:
   train_token += str(i)
```