# what does the error "expected spacy.tokens.span.Span, got str" mean in spacy

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

What does the error "expected spacy.tokens.span.Span, got str" mean in spacy? How does one convert a list into a span or token type and vice versa ?

Here is the code that I am working on

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlpsm = en_core_web_sm.load()
text = input("Please enter your words\n")
doc=nlp(text)
listmain= [t.text for t in doc]


finalwor=[]
fil = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ["person"]]
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    if chunk not in fil:
        finalwor=list(doc.noun_chunks)

#next I am trying to check if the words in 'listmain' are present in the list 'finalwor'

for fin in listmain:
    if fin in finalwor:
       print("word exists in the list and it is", fin)
    elif fin not in finalwor:
       print("word does not exists in the list")
```

when I run the above code, i get the below error pointing at the line

```
if fin in finalwor
```

"expected spacy.tokens.span.Span, got str"

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A Span is multiple Tokens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['string' has incorrect type (expected str, got spacy.tokens.doc.Doc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53588518/string-has-incorrect-type-expected-str-got-spacy-tokens-doc-doc)

Comment: @APhillips thanks for the suggestion, have added the minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should fix your issue. Please ensure it's performing properly based on your input text.

```py
for fin in finalwor:
    if fin.text in listmain:
       print("word exists in the list and it is", fin.text)
    elif fin.text not in finalwor:
       print("word does not exists in the list")
```